# Differentiating between mass number (A) and activity (A) in a nomenclature/glossary

Tags: mass, terminology, radioactivity

I'm not sure if this is the best place to ask this question, but as it's related to the terminology of nuclear physics I thought it would probably be a logical place to start.

I'm currently writing my thesis, and in the section on radioactive decay I talk about the mass number and activity of radionuclides.  The problem is that the notation for both these terms is *A*, which is likely to become confusing later on.  Can anybody recommend a commonly accepted alternative symbol/notation for either term, or suggest a way that I differentiate between the two in the text and nomenclature/glossary?

Many thanks!

Comment: why don't you ask your advisor? i guess you could use a caligraphic $\mathcal{A}$ and regular $A$. not physics, off topic: make a latex macro so you can change them easily later.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic cf. [this](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/1083/2451) meta post.

Answer (score 0):

My textbook uses $R$ for activity as corresponding to the decay rate.